# How to prevent empty input in text input form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> My Shopping List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shoppinglist.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400|Advent+Pro:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="shoppinglist.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p id="shoppinglist"> My Shopping List App</p>

<input type="text" name="user" class="entertext">
<input type="button" value="Enter" class="returnkey">
<br>
<br>
    <ol></ol>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
        var item = $("input[type='text']").val();
        $("ol").append("<li style='display:none;'>"+ item+"<input type='checkbox'></li><br />");
        $("li:last").show("clip");
    });
    $("input[type='text']").keyup(function(event) {

       if(event.keyCode == 13) {

          $("input[type='button']").click(); 
       }
   });
   $("ol").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
       $(this).parent().remove();   
   });

});
```

How do I create JavaScript for someone whose entering empty? So something to prevent them from empty text input?

Comment: Use jquery.validate.js or simply check the input value `if ($('.selector').val() == '') { do something }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the value of the text input is equal to a blank string:

```
$("input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
    var item = $("input[type='text']").val();

    //start new code
    if ($.trim(item) === '') {
        alert("Please Enter Something!");
        return false;
    }
    //end new code

    $("ol").append("<li style='display:none;'>"+ item+"<input type='checkbox'></li><br />");
    $("li:last").show("clip");
});
```

`$.trim()` removes any extra white-space, to make sure the input doesn't just have white-space as a value.

Comment: why u have put three '=' .. i know it is typed condition but why u need it here .. it will work even if u have `if ($.trim(item) == '')`

Comment: @Dhaval case-sensitive.

Comment: @Dhaval It's my default to code like that. It's harder to make mistakes with your conditionals if you check against value and type. I believe it's also marginally faster.

Comment: @ShannonYeh This replaces your current `input[type='button']` `click` event handler. Essentially you just need to add the new conditional statement that stops the execution of the event handler if the value of the input is a blank string.

Comment: @Omar javascript is always case sensitive even if you put == or === in condition

Comment: @Jasper i got your point .. so we should always put '===' in condition

Comment: @Dhaval That's up to you. There are caveats to using `==` and `!=`. E.g. `false == 0` returns `true` and `false === 0` returns `false`. Sometimes it can be useful to evaluate using the truthy/falsy style rather than a strict true/false (i.e. `===` and `!==`).

Comment: how do you check for empty spaces @Dhaval

Comment: @ShannonYeh i will have same code wirtten by Jasper the only diff is i always use '==' not '===' but if you  have more complected  validation then you can use  jquery.validate.js

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('.returnkey').on('click', function() {

  var string = $.trim($('.entertext').val());

  if (string == '') {
     alert('Field is empty');
     return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you check for empty spaces